# django - creating users making their fullname unique

Tags: python, django

i need small help in the logic of creating user making his name unique:

i have a django user profile. i am creating users in this way:

```
fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
random_username = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 8))
new_user = User.objects.create_user(random_username, email, passwort)
##update siteprofile of this new user
userprofile = new_user.get_profile()

""" 
    i need to make this fullname unique with this logic:
    for example john is the fullname of new user. i need to check if there are 
    other johns in db, if there is another user with this name, i will name the
    user with 'john1'. if there are 2, the new user will get the name 'john3'
    how can I check this in db in some efficient way?

"""
userprofile.name = fullname
userprofile.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check for the `IntegrityError` on save and update accordingly.  Doing a query to check for the names existence creates a race condition where you can search then two separate threads try to create the same fullname at the same time.

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def set_fullname(userprofile, fullname, i=0):
    new_fullname = u"{}{}".format(fullname, str(i) if i else '')
    try:
        userprofile.fullname = new_fullname
        userprofile.save()

        transaction.commit()

        return userprofile
    except IntegrityError:
        transaction.rollback()

        i += 1
        # Just recursively try until we a valid name. This could be problematic if you
        # have a TON of users, but in that case you could just the filter before then to see
        # what number to start from.
        return set_fullname(userprofile, fullname, i)

userprofile = set_fullname(userprofile, fullname)
```

Comment: very nice, this makes sure that two people from 2 parts of the world dont set the same name, right?

Comment: That's correct.  And it does it the db level, so you won't run into the rare chance that two threads are setting the same name at the same time.

Comment: ``userprofile.fullname = fullname`` should be ``userprofile.fullname = new_fullname``, right?

Comment: @doniyor Yup, thanks, forgot to update it when I changed the var name.

Comment: ``return set_fullname(fullname, i)`` should also be ``return set_fullname(userprofile, fullname, i)`` right?

Comment: @doniyor: Yup, fixed :)

Comment: hi, sorry, i am getting ``current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block``, any idea why? :(

Comment: @doniyor You have to rollback the transaction otherwise the db will be in a bad state.  See how to do it in my update

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose it would be better to use form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/. But if you won't to use forms, you can do it that way:

```
i = 0
orig_fullname = fullname
created = False
while not created:
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(name=fullname)
    if not created:
        i+=1
        fullname = orig_fullname + str(i)
# there you have new user's profile
```

Note, that field 'name' in UserProfile model must have unique=True parameter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: sounds nice. after while-true i will get the latest new fullname right?

Comment: You want to try and insert it and catch the IntegrityError, so the uniqueness is handled at the db level, and you avoid race conditions.

Comment: @doniyor It was easier to just throw it into an answer

Comment: @sdolan, you are right, I forgot about race condition. I have edited answer to avoid it.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov That would fetch an existing UserProfile with the same name and not create a new one with the incremented number identifier.  See my answer on how you do it correctly.

Comment: @sdolan You are wrong, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov nice, but i have already a userprofile. so get_or_create isnot needed in my case

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov No, no I'm not. What I said before is correct and you have the additional problem that get_or_create adds another race condition on itself between the get and create.  Just see my answer, that's how you do it correctly.

Comment: @sdolan get and create is not one atomic operation then, right?

Comment: get_or_create use transaction.atomic. If your user already have profile my answer not fit your case, as well sdolan's answer, I agree.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov Yeah, so you'd still throw the IntegrityError in that race condition and the atomic transaction would be rolled back.

Comment: @sdolan, ok, it seems that your decision is better.